# Plotly - how to display y values when hovering on two subplots sharing x-axis

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I have two subplots sharing x-axis, but it only shows the y-value of one subplot not both. I want the hover-display to show y values from both subplots.

Here is what is showing right now:
[image: image1]

But I want it to show y values from the bottom chart as well even if I am hovering my mouse on the top chart and vice versa.

Here's my code:

```
title = 'Price over time'
err = 'Price'


fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1,
                    vertical_spacing = 0.05,
                    shared_xaxes=True,
                    subplot_titles=(title,""))

# A
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x= A_error['CloseDate'], 
                         y = A_error[err], 
                         line_color = 'green',
                         marker_color = 'green',
                         mode = 'lines+markers',
                         showlegend = True,
                         name = "A",
                         stackgroup = 'one'),
              row = 1,
              col = 1,
              secondary_y = False)

# B
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x= B_error['CloseDate'], 
                         y = B_error[err], 
                         line_color = 'blue',
                         mode = 'lines+markers',
                         showlegend = True,
                         name = "B",
                         stackgroup = 'one'),
              row = 2,
              col = 1,
              secondary_y = False)

fig.update_yaxes(tickprefix = '$')
fig.add_hline(y=0, line_width=3, line_dash="dash", line_color="black")

fig.update_layout(#height=600, width=1400, 
                  hovermode = "x unified",
                  legend_traceorder="normal")
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Edit: At this time, I don't think a Unified hovermode across the subplots will be provided. I got the rationale for this from [here](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.js/issues/4755). It does affect some features, but [this](https://community.plotly.com/t/unified-hovermode-with-sublots/37606) can be applied to work around it. In your example, the horizontal line does not appear on both graphs.
So, I have added two horizontal lines in line mode for scatter plots to accommodate this.
With the two stock prices, you have set a threshold value for each. Your objective is the same threshold value, so please modify that.

```
import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import yfinance as yf

df = yf.download("AAPL MSFT", start="2022-01-01", end="2022-07-01", group_by='ticker')
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

import plotly.express as px
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

title = 'Price over time'
err = 'Price'

fig = make_subplots(rows=2, cols=1,
                    vertical_spacing = 0.05,
                    shared_xaxes=True,
                    subplot_titles=(title,""))

# AAPL
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x = df['Date'], 
                         y = df[('AAPL', 'Close')], 
                         line_color = 'green',
                         marker_color = 'green',
                         mode = 'lines+markers',
                         showlegend = True,
                         name = "AAPL",
                         stackgroup = 'one'),
              row = 1,
              col = 1,
              secondary_y = False)
# APPL $150 horizontal line
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['Date'],
                         y=[125]*len(df['Date']),
                         mode='lines',
                         line_width=3,
                         line_color='black',
                         line_dash='dash',
                         showlegend=False,
                         name='APPL'
                        ),
              row=1,
              col=1,
              secondary_y=False)
                                   

# MSFT
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x= df['Date'], 
                         y = df[('MSFT', 'Close')], 
                         line_color = 'blue',
                         mode = 'lines+markers',
                         showlegend = True,
                         name = "MSFT",
                         stackgroup = 'one'),
              row = 2,
              col = 1,
              secondary_y = False)
# MSFT $150 horizontal line
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=df['Date'],
                         y=[150]*len(df['Date']),
                         mode='lines',
                         line_width=3,
                         line_color='black',
                         line_dash='dash',
                         showlegend=False,
                         name='MSFT'
                        ),
              row=2,
              col=1,
              secondary_y=False)


fig.update_yaxes(tickprefix = '$')
fig.update_xaxes(type='date', range=[df['Date'].min(),df['Date'].max()])

#fig.add_hline(y=0, line_width=3, line_dash="dash", line_color="black")
fig.update_layout(#height=600, width=1400,
    hovermode = "x unified",
    legend_traceorder="normal")
fig.update_traces(xaxis='x2')

fig.show()

enter code here
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, but this does not quite meet my needs. So there is no way to get value from B subplot on hover? We can only draw a vertical line that cuts across both subplots?

Comment: Also the thing is that they don't share the same df. They are using different dataframes in my code..

Comment: Have you tried my code? If you move your mouse over the B subplot, you will see the B hover. If you are not satisfied with my answer, the only way is to combine them into a single data frame and make two hovers on a single graph. I see an example in the [references](https://plotly.com/python/hover-text-and-formatting/#unified-hovermode). The expected functionality is not currently provided is also the answer.

Comment: Why does introducing `update_traces(xaxis='x2)` remove the horizontal line on the first plot? Is there a way to have the horizontal line on both plots while keeping the vertical line?

Comment: Please confirm that I have considered drawing two lines and have addressed this in the line mode of the scatter plot.

Answer (score 3):

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots


def plotly_stl(results):

    fig = make_subplots(
        rows=3 + len(results.seasonal.columns),
        cols=1,
        shared_xaxes=False,
    )

    precision = 2
    customdataName = [
        results.observed.name.capitalize(),
        results.trend.name.capitalize(),
        results.seasonal.columns[0].capitalize(),
        results.seasonal.columns[1].capitalize(),
        results.resid.name.capitalize(),
    ]
    customdata = np.stack(
        (
            results.observed,
            results.trend,
            results.seasonal[results.seasonal.columns[0]],
            results.seasonal[results.seasonal.columns[1]],
            results.resid,
        ), 
        axis=-1
    )
    fig.append_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            name=customdataName[0], 
            mode='lines', 
            x=results.observed.index,
            y=results.observed,
            line=dict(
                shape='linear',
                # color='blue', # 'rgb(100, 10, 100)', 
                width=2,
                # dash='dash',
            ),
            customdata=customdata,                                 
            hovertemplate='<br>'.join([
                'Datetime: %{x:%Y-%m-%d:%h}',
                '<b>'+customdataName[0]+'</b><b>'+f": %{{y:.{precision}f}}"+'</b>',
                customdataName[1] + ": %{customdata[1]:.2f}",
                customdataName[2] + ": %{customdata[2]:.2f}",
                customdataName[3] + ": %{customdata[3]:.2f}",
                customdataName[4] + ": %{customdata[4]:.2f}",
                '<extra></extra>',
            ]),
            showlegend=False,
        ),
        row=1,
        col=1,
    )
    
    fig['layout']['yaxis']['title'] = customdataName[0]
    fig.append_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            name=customdataName[1], 
            mode='lines', 
            x=results.trend.index,
            y=results.trend,
            line=dict(
                shape='linear',
                #color='blue', #'rgb(100, 10, 100)', 
                width=2,
                #dash='dash'
            ),
            customdata=customdata,                                 
            hovertemplate='<br>'.join([
                'Datetime: %{x:%Y-%m-%d:%h}',
                '<b>'+customdataName[1]+'</b><b>'+f": %{{y:.{precision}f}}"+'</b>',
                customdataName[0] + ": %{customdata[0]:.2f}",
                customdataName[2] + ": %{customdata[2]:.2f}",
                customdataName[3] + ": %{customdata[3]:.2f}",
                customdataName[4] + ": %{customdata[4]:.2f}",
                '<extra></extra>'
            ]),
            showlegend=False,
        ),
        row=2,
        col=1,
    )

    fig['layout']['yaxis2']['title'] = customdataName[1]

    for i in range(len(results.seasonal.columns)):
        another = 3 - i
        fig.append_trace(
            go.Scatter(
                name=customdataName[2+i], 
                mode='lines', 
                x=results.seasonal.index,
                y=results.seasonal[results.seasonal.columns[i]],
                line=dict(
                    shape='linear',
                    # color='blue', #'rgb(100, 10, 100)', 
                    width=2,
                    # dash='dash'
                ),
                customdata=customdata,           
                hovertemplate='<br>'.join([
                    'Datetime: %{x:%Y-%m-%d:%h}',
                    '<b>'+customdataName[2+i]+'</b><b>'+f": %{{y:.{precision}f}}"+'</b>',
                    customdataName[0] + ": %{customdata[0]:.2f}",
                    customdataName[1] + ": %{customdata[1]:.2f}",
                    customdataName[another] + f": %{{customdata[{another}]:.{precision}f}}",
                    customdataName[4] + ": %{customdata[4]:.2f}",
                    '<extra></extra>',
                ]), 
                showlegend=False,
            ),
            row=3 + i,
            col=1,
        )
        fig['layout']['yaxis'+str(3+i)]['title'] = customdataName[2+i]
    
    fig.append_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            name=customdataName[4], 
            mode='lines', 
            x=results.resid.index,
            y=results.resid,
            line=dict(
                shape='linear',
                # color='blue', #'rgb(100, 10, 100)', 
                width=2,
                # dash='dash'
            ),   
            customdata=customdata,                                 
            hovertemplate='<br>'.join([
                'Datetime: %{x:%Y-%m-%d:%h}',
                '<b>'+customdataName[4]+'</b><b>'+f": %{{y:.{precision}f}}"+'</b>',
                customdataName[0] + ": %{customdata[0]:.2f}",
                customdataName[1] + ": %{customdata[1]:.2f}",
                customdataName[2] + ": %{customdata[2]:.2f}",
                customdataName[3] + ": %{customdata[3]:.2f}",
                '<extra></extra>',
            ]),                            
            showlegend=False,
        ),
        row=3 + len(results.seasonal.columns),
        col=1,
    )
    fig['layout']['yaxis'+str(3+len(results.seasonal.columns))]['title'] = customdataName[-1]
    fig['layout']['xaxis'+str(3+len(results.seasonal.columns))]['title'] = 'Datetime'

    fig.update_layout(
        height=800,
        width=1000,
        legend_tracegroupgap = 330,
        hovermode='x unified',
        legend_traceorder="normal",
        # plot_bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)',
    )
    fig.update_traces(xaxis='x{}'.format(str(3+len(results.seasonal.columns))))
    fig.show()
    plotly_stl(results_mstl)
```

You can see the complete code [here](https://blog.csdn.net/Linli522362242/article/details/128760927).

[image]

[Here](https://blog.csdn.net/Linli522362242/article/details/128760927) is another solution:

[image]

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).